# R Decision column in lavaan package modification indices output

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I'm working with `modindices` command in `R`, `lavaan` package:

```
modindices(fit,power=TRUE,delta=0.1,alpha=0.05,high.power=0.75)
```

Could someone describe what different notions in decision column of *modification indices* mean? for example (i),*****,epc?

## Output:

```
127  F5 =~ V78 17.165   -0.513   -0.513   0.1  0.378 0.094      ***
128  F5 =~ V47 10.654    0.400    0.400   0.1  0.361 0.092      ***
129  F5 =~ V79  1.036    0.126    0.126   0.1  0.331 0.089      (i)
130  F5 =~ V60 16.374   -0.269   -0.269   0.1  1.307 0.208      ***
131  F5 =~ V75  0.000    0.001    0.001   0.1  1.309 0.208      (i)
132  F5 =~ V62  2.331    0.102    0.102   0.1  1.307 0.208      (i)
133  F5 =~ V51 10.848    0.227    0.227   0.1  1.252 0.201      ***
```

Comment: I see only two outcomes in the decision column: *** and (i). EPC is expected value change (when introducing the modification) and is presented in other columns. This is a guess, but I imagine the *** and (i) refer to the decision to keep or reject the mod index. There is nothing in lavaan help about this, but perhaps reading about power analysis will help. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the function's code, it appears that:

`***` means that the modification index is significant and the power is *not* high.
`epc` means that the modification index is significant and the power is high.
`(i)` means that the modification index is *not* significant and the power is *not* high.

The cut-offs for significance and high power are set with the `alpha` and `high.power` parameters, respectively.